# AjaxLink updateAjaxAttributes - AjaxCallListener getPrecondition

Tags: ajax, wicket, hyperlink, wicket-6

I stucked during migration from Wicket 1.5 to 6.6.

Earlier *AjaxLink* allowed to override *getAjaxCallDecorator()* method and wrap the script with *preDecorateScript(CharSequence script)*.

Now recommended way is using *AjaxCallListener* with *getPrecondition(Component component)* method. But how can I wrap the source script using *Component component* parameter?

Comment: I think I figured out it. Instead wrapping the script in Wicket 6 one can split in into two phases: before ajax call (using *getBeforeHandler()* for instance) and after ajax call (*getCompleteHandler()*)

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if i understand you correctly. We do it this way:

```
public class MyAjaxCallListener implements IAjaxCallListener{

    @Override
    public CharSequence getBeforeHandler(Component component) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
        return YOUR_SCRIPT;
    }

    // ...     not needed overrides can return null

}
```

Then you add it through an `Behavior` to your `AjaxLink`.

```
ajaxLink.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
   @Override
   protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
   //do stuff
   }

   @Override
   protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
      super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
      attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new MyAjaxCallListener());
   }
});
```

Comment: It seems good. The problem is that earlier *CharSequence script* was a method parameter and I was able to wrap it (for instance add or replace something in the script). Script was different depending on context. Now the method parameter is *Component component* and I can't add or replace somting, I have to return the complete script.

Comment: Ahh ok i think i understand - you want to modify the JS generated by wicket. I've did'nt do this so my answer only partially answer your needs.